# How to use rest war for development

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, war

I have a REST application packed as a war file from which I have to develop a UI in java+Spring (since this app will do some stuff besides consuming the already created web app). Is there a way to add that war file to my eclipse development environment? The only thing i could came up was exporting the new app as war and put it together to the existing war and test them in some test environment. (both apps will be in the same server in the future).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can import as project

Comment: It worked! How about write an answere so that i can choose it?